# Creating a table with dynamic json column - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables containing array columns: `config_table`, `main_table` and `field_table`. My objective is to get an `output_table` that can have variable column names (and obviosuly values) depending on what is configured in the `config_table`.

`config_table`:

```
type_id  fields  feild_ids
   1      {A}       {1}
   1     {B,C}     {2,3}  
   1      {D}       {4}
```

`main_table`:

```
type_id  value 
  1        12
  1        34
  2        56
  2        78
  3        99
```

`field_table`:

```
value      field_data
 12       {"1": "Hello",
           "2": "foo",
           "3": "bar",
           "4": "Hi",
           "5": "ignore_this",
           "6": "ignore_this_too" }

 34       {"1": "Iam",
           "2": "out",
           "3": "of",
           "4": "words",
           "5": "orange",
           "6": "banana" }

 56           ...
 78           ...
 99           ...
```

---

EDIT

Since having dynamic/variable column names will not be feasible, the ideal `output_table` format would be:

```
  type_id  value                  json_data
    1       12   {"A": "Hello", "B-C": "foo-bar", D: "Hi"}
    1       34   {"A": "Iam", "B-C": "out-of", D: "words"}
```

I am trying to realize a general solution that would allow me to create `output_table` for `N` values in a single "`field_ids`" in `config_table`.

---

EDIT 2

removed the redundant `type` column, added fields `5` and `6` to `field_table.field_data` as well as `type_id` `2` and `3` to `main_table.type_id` (which need to be ignored in `output_table` because of their absence in `config_table`) and to make the question easier to understand

---

Comment: This is not possible with relational tables - you will have to use a JSON field to accommodate your variable/dynamic data model.

Comment: I see. By JSON field do you mean bring together columns A, B-C and D to a single column (say json_data) which would be : {"A": "Hello", "B-C": "foo-bar", D: "Hi"} ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. No other options.

Comment: I think you're missing the `"value"` column in your understanding. If you look at the second row in `output_table`, it has `"A": "Iam"` for the value `34`, which it picked up from `field_table.field_data` for the value `34`

Comment: The third row in `config_table` corresponds to the field `D` (field_id `4`) and the required data for this field was therefore populated in `output_table.json_data`

Comment: I have made some edits - removed the redundant `type` column, added fields `5` and `6` to `field_table.field_data` as well as `type_id` `2` and `3` to `main_table.type_id` (which need to be ignored in `output_table` because of their absence in `config_table`) and to make the question easier to understand

Comment: Like I said - the only way to achieve a dynamic schema/structure of your data is to use JSON. Relational tables require statically defined columns. Maybe you're trying to use the wrong tool - take a look at NoSQL solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This gave me the desired output:

```
select M.type_id,
       M.value,
       --F.field_data,
       JSON_OBJECT(ARRAY( select TD.temp_keys
                                from ( select array_to_string(TMD.fields, '-') as temp_keys,
                                                array_to_string(TMD.field_values, '-') as temp_values
                                          from   (select MC.fields,
                                                         MC.field_ids,
                                                         array(select TF.value
                                                               from jsonb_each_text(F.field_data) TF
                                                               where TF.key::integer = any(MC.field_ids)) as field_values
                                                    from config_table MC
                                                   --where MC.field_ids = any(F.fields)
                                          ) TMD
                                      ) TD 
                            ),
                  ARRAY(    select TD.temp_values
                                from ( select array_to_string(TMD.fields, '-') as temp_keys,
                                                array_to_string(TMD.field_values, '-') as temp_values
                                          from   (select MC.fields,
                                                         MC.field_ids,
                                                         array(select TF.value
                                                               from jsonb_each_text(F.field_data) TF
                                                               where TF.key::integer = any(MC.field_ids)) as field_values
                                                    from main_table MC
                                                   --where MC.field_ids = any(F.fields)
                                          ) TMD
                               ) TD  
                           )
                  )
from main_table M
inner join field_table F
on M.value = F.value
where M.type_id in (select distinct CC.type_id from config_table CC)
```